# How to connect an external id to another record using apex

Tags: apex, externalid, merge, unique-field

I currently have a situation where new contacts are created with the chance of creating duplicates. The existing contacts have an external id. Since it is not possible to merge external ids with standard salesforce I assume I would have to resolve this with apex.

Would the following solution work or am I missing something:

1. Store the external id in another field
2. Remove the external id from the unique field
3. Merge the contacts
4. Restore the external id on the merged record

Above in a  single transaction so it can be rolled back if there are issues.

*** UPDATE

Following is working:

- exid__c set as Text(255) (External ID) (Unique Case Insensitive)
- Updating the external id directly on the new record before merge

  ```java
  List<Contact> con = [select id, exid__c  from contact where exid__c = '1234567' Limit 1];
  Contact newCon = New Contact(lastname = 'Test' + system.Datetime.now());
  insert newCon;
  newCon.exid__c = con[0].exid__c;
  merge newCon con[0];
  ```

What I am still concerned about if this could give issues for external systems?

Comment: Have you tried your proposed solution to test it out? What didn't work?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I added an update. Still I would appreciate to know if I am missing something

Comment: Is there any syncing or integration with this external system based on this field? If so, are there any relevant details on that (frequency, timing, flow of information (one-way), etc).

Comment: @ KrisGoncalves There is a sync with an external system every 12 hours to update the external system with the info on contacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we went ahead with the proposed solution which did not give issues:

Updating the external id directly on the new record before merge

```
List<Contact> con = [select id, exid__c  from contact where exid__c = '1234567' Limit 1];
Contact newCon = New Contact(lastname = 'Test' + system.Datetime.now());
insert newCon;
newCon.exid__c = con[0].exid__c;
merge newCon con[0];
```